# Windows disappeared after installing Ubuntu encrypted

Tags: dual-boot, windows, encryption, ecryptfs

My problem is I lost Windows after **reinstalling** Ubuntu 14.04, because I reinstalled Ubuntu using encryption. From the beginning:

- 1) When I bought this laptop Windows 8 was already installed.
- 2) I installed Ubuntu 14.04.
- 3) I was using both perfectly.
- 4) I had some    trouble with Ubuntu, I reinstalled Ubuntu **using
  encryption** (my    mistake).
- 5) Now I can only boot Ubuntu, and I have got my whole    drive
  encrypted.

I tried to disable home folder encryption following [this guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/116179/how-to-disable-home-folder-encryption-after-installing-ubuntu/) but I couldn't.

So, the question is:

### Is Windows still installed (but encrypted) and that's why I can't boot it? If so, is there any way to restore it?

I hope you can help me guys.

Greetings!

Edit:

Added screenshot of my GParted status. Click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZEg0.png) to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not your Ubuntu install is encrypted has nothing to do with your issue, it very much looks like you told the installer to put it over Windows and onto the whole disk (apart from the uefi boot partitions).

The encryption only plays a role in gparted not being able to look into the luks-disk layout ubuntu created.

[On the up side, your better off without Windows]

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying this. I guess you're right, the only use I was giving to Windows was using some specific software from the University. I can always reinstall it, if that is really necessary.

Thanks to all for your replies.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the OP question: **No**, windows is not encrypted. Either it has been wipe out by the ubuntu installation **or** it is still there waiting to be boot up.

You need to look at other thread to look for your windows and how to enable booting it

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My whole hard disk is encrypted, so which _other thread_ should I start with in order to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I guess grub didn't updated good after your **reinstallation**. You could try this to get windows back on the boot list:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: @Tomas15v Thanks for your reply. I tried using this. My boot list is still "Ubuntu, Ubuntu advanced options, System Conf". Not Windows, anywhere. Not even in my partitions.

Comment: Ehm, Than I am afraid you have overwritten windows :(.

Comment: I added a link to a screenshot in my question. There you can see my GParted. Main partition under LUKS, and this warning: "LUKS is not available". I don't get it.

Comment: I am pretty sure windows can't survive a harddrive that is encrypted on the linux way :(.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wipe your hard drive to encrypt whole drive. Therefore, Windows is not in your hard drive anymore. Windows and other data on the hard have been erased. If you want to Windows, you have to install it again.